# Manipulate within Manipulate

Tags: front-end, manipulate, dynamic, kernel

Since the original post of **mine**, which is below, is too long, too complicated and time-consuming for others, I tried to mimic the same structure with a very simple `code`. I want to calculate $x=alfa+beta$ by choosing a random seed. If output $x$ is less than 0.5, then I analyze $x$, otherwise I **only** want to *dynamically* change $beta$ (which is the case below), while keeping the *seed* value of $alfa$ unchanged. But this change in $beta$ should be done only if I click on the slider for $beta$. If I get $x1>=0.5$, then I analyze $x1$. The logic is similar to `Do` loop, with a difference that I am trying to adjust $alfa$ and $beta$ to get the desired output.

Any idea is appreciated.

```
 DynamicModule[{alfa, beta},
 Manipulate[
  SeedRandom[seed];
  alfa = RandomReal[];
  beta = RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
  x = alfa + beta;
  If[x < 0.5, x, x1 = alfa + beta],
  {{seed, 1, "seed"}, 1, 100, 1},
  {{alfa, 0.5, "alfa"}, 0, 1, 0.02},
  {Slider[Dynamic[beta], {-1, 1}], Dynamic[beta]},
  TrackedSymbols :> True, ContinuousAction -> False, 
  SynchronousUpdating -> True
  ]
 ]
```

I am editing the above `code` with `Manipulate` within `Manipulate`, Let us call this edited `code` as **Edit 1**:

```
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[seed];
 Pause[2];
 alfa := RandomReal[1, 20];
 Manipulate[
  Plot[{Sin[a y], Sin[a1 y]}, {y, 0, 10}],
  Row[{Control[{a, alfa, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}],
  Row[{Control[{a1, alfa*(1 + 0.5), Animator, 
      AnimationRunning -> False}]}],
  SaveDefinitions -> True
  ],
 {{seed, 1, "seed"}, 1, 100, 1}
 ]
```

**Edit 1** produces the desired output, though I like to make a `Slider` for $0.5$ in the second `Control` command. As one may see, the first Manipulate randomizes $alfa$ and the second `Manipulate` adjusts $alfa$ to the desired level. In this example, the adjustment value is set to $0.5$ in the second `Control` command. If I can make this adjustment value as a *Dynamic Slider* (for updating purposes), that will answer my question.

Comment: You have a number of problems. The variables alfa and beta are set in the code to be random, yet you also specify the values of alfa and beta in the sliders (parameters of the Manipulate). You can do one or the other, but not both. Also, you can porbably accomplish your complete task without use of Dynamic -- the Manipulate is already a Dynamic object that can do what you seem to be asking.

Comment: @bill s: After `If` statement, the `Manipulate` command will be closed, but then I want to be able to adjust $alfa$ and $beta$ to the desired values. That is why I want to use $alfa$ and $beta$ in the `Slider` formats. However, I want to adjust the parameters one at a time, not like `SeedRandom[]` does. I hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what you are trying to do. The If statement is vacuous because it says if x<0.5 then x (=alfa + beta) else x1 (=alfa + beta). But that aside, you have to decide whether alfa and beta are set randomly or are set by a slider. You can't do both.

Comment: @bill s: To explain in more detail, I edited my question with a new example. I hope that this new example illustrates what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question formulated as in **Edit 1.** Let me first give the `code` that answers to my question and then briefly explain what it does.

```
Clear[alfa, newalfa, a1, a2, x, s, chn];
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[s];
 alfa = RandomReal[1, 20];
 newalfa = alfa*(1 + chn);
 Manipulate[
  Plot[{Sin[a1 x], Sin[a2 x]}, {x, 0, 10}],
  Row[{Control[{a1, alfa, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}], (* model 1 *)
  Row[{Control[{a2, newalfa, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}]
  ], (* model 2 *)
 {{s, 1, "s"}, 1, 100, 1},
 {{chn, 0, "change"}, -0.2, 0.2, 0.02}
 ]
```

This `Manipulate` inside `Manipulate` does this: The 1st `Manipulate` randomly (controlled by $s$) picks 20 numbers between 0 and 1 to create a variable $alfa$, which is then used to create another variable called $newalfa$ by introducing a change parameter $chn$. These variables are used in the 2nd `Manipulate` to compare two model plots, different from each other only with respect to the two parameters $a1$ and $a2$. The 2nd `Manipulate` helps me to visually adjust and compare the two models. The `Slider`s $s$ and $change$ set $alfa$ and $newalfa$, respectively, preparing the model parameters to be compared. In this formulation, model 1 can be thought as a **benchmark** model that is compared with the **simulated** model 2. This is the answer I was after.

I extended the above `code` to include `CommunityGraphPlot` with `FindGraphCommunities` to dynamically see the effects of changes in $alfa$ on the community structure. Here is the `code` (together with the output generated) to achieve this task. Below, everything is fine.

```
Clear[alfa, tao, newalfa, newtao, G, Gcom, mat, matG, aa, wG, wGcom];
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[s];
 G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, 
   DirectedEdges -> True];
 Gcom = CommunityGraphPlot[G, FindGraphCommunities[G], 
   CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, Method -> "Modularity"]; 
 mat = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
 matG = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*mat;
 aa = SparseArray[matG];
 wG = Graph[aa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> aa["NonzeroValues"],
    DirectedEdges -> True];
 wGcom = CommunityGraphPlot[wG, FindGraphCommunities[wG], 
   CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, Method -> "Modularity"];

 alfa = RandomReal[1, n];
 tao = RandomReal[1, n];
 newalfa = alfa*(1 + chnAlfa);
 newtao = tao*(1 + chnTao);
(* insert 1 *)

 Manipulate[
(* insert 2 *)
  plot = Plot[
    {Sin[a1 x], Sin[a2 x]}, {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x, Sin[a x]}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{"sin(a1 x)", "sin(a2 x)"}, Below]
    ];
  Grid[{   
    {Text["Benchmark vs Simulated Model"], Text["digraph (n,d): G"], 
     Text["communities in\nAdjacency G"], 
     Text["communities in\nWeighted G"]}, {plot, G, Gcom, wGcom}   
        }],
  Row[{Control[{a1, alfa*tao, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}],
  Row[{Control[{a2, newalfa*newtao, Animator, 
      AnimationRunning -> False}]}],
(* insert 3 *)
  ],
 {{s, 1, "s"}, 1, 100, 1},
 {{n, 20, "n"}, 1, 50, 1},
 {{d, 0.05, "d"}, 0, 1, 0.02},
 {{chnAlfa, 0, "\[CapitalDelta]alfa"}, -0.2, 0.2, 0.02},
 {{chnTao, 0, "\[CapitalDelta]tao"}, -0.2, 0.2, 0.02}
 ]
```

[image]

When I edit the above `code` by *inserting* the following three *inserts*, the `code` does not work, although I apply the same logic as in $plot$. `(* Insert 1 *)` is:

```
AT = alfa*tao;
newAT = newalfa*newtao;
newAdT = Array[(Sqrt[newalfa]/newtao) &, {n,
   n}];  (* a list of n matrices, each with (n,n) dimension *)
```

`(* Insert 2 *)` is:

```
bb = SparseArray[a3*matG]; 
wGbb =
Graph[bb["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> bb["NonzeroValues"], 
  DirectedEdges -> True];
wGbbCom = 
  CommunityGraphPlot[wGbb, FindGraphCommunities[wGbb], 
   CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray, Method -> "Modularity"];
```

`(* Insert 3 *)` is:

```
Row[{Control[{a3, newAdT, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}]
```

Can someone tell me where I make the mistake in adding these **3 inserts**?

Comment: I had the above problem for sometime but only recently was I inspired by @FredSimons's interactivity course as well as his one of early comments about `Manipulate` in `Manipulate`. Since my answer is related to his earlier comments and does not use `DynamicModule` at all, I like to update the title of the current post to **Manipulate within Manipulate**.